# Facebook Like Button display's Switch and image

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, switch-statement, profile

I have a problem with the Facebook Like button to where if a person is an admin of multiple pages / account, instead of the button displaying it shows a small box with a "Switch" link and the person's image. The same as explained here... http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/111826392293111/

I am using the default code provided by Facebook, not any special code. Any ideas or unfixable bug?

Comment: see also : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546072/facebook-like-button-breaks-when-logged-in-as-page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369247/how-to-make-the-facebook-like-button-display-none-when-logged-in-as-page

Answer (score 3):

if you get the "switch link", than you're currently using facebook as a page and therefore can't access the social plugin. go back to facebook.com, change your identity back to your user profile and reload the page with the social plugin. it's not a bug in your implementation or from facebook at all.

Comment: Well, it IS a bug in facebook's code, since the expanding "switch" link box expands erratically, sometimes to the foot of the page, sometimes all the way to left of the page, obscuring content and destroying the page. This is in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Just use: data-height="60" data-width="60" for example, and limit the expansion of the box.