# How To Make The Facebook Like Button Display None When Logged In As Page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, switch-statement, share

I have the Facebook like button on my site http://theganjagirls.com ... everything looks and works fine when I'm logged into my Facebook account... But when I'm logged in as a page admin, the Facebook like button displays a "switch" link inside a big white box. Ive seen this happen on many big sites so I know its a problem with Facebook.
I just went on to teespring.com/ganjagirls and they cleverly make the Facebook like button simply display:none when your logged in as a page admin.

So my question is: How do i make the Facebook like button display:none only if the viewing user is logged in to Facebook as a page admin?

I tried to do it my self by rapping the Facebook code in a container and using some JavaScript... but I'm amateur and I couldn't get it to work properly.

Here is what I got so far in CodePen: http://www.codepen.io/nouveau/pen/zfcLu.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little script to set a timeout function and check the width of the widget

```
var timer;
$(window).load(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('.fb-like').width() === 0) {
            $('.fb-like').hide();
            console.log('face');

        }
    }, 1000); // using 1000 milliseconds to work around load race
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sfREk/16/)**

Be aware you may run into a load-race. If the script runs before the widget loads this method may fail...

Comment: Good idea, but the logic seems wrong. "If the span is greater than 200 pixels, then hide it." ? Your fiddle is broken. For the like box, the span has zero width if the user is logged in as a page. If the user is logged in as a person, then the like box loads and the span has a width. Here's the corrected logic: http://jsfiddle.net/alexbell/J8s3T/

Comment: @Ben I think facebook has been playing with their plug in... see update

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that. Unless Facebook [has made code for it](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), You can't just check for yourself.

Please remember that if you put in the default code for a Facebook like button, it will respond appropriately if the user is logged in.

Good luck!

Comment: I have been "just checking my self" for several days now... cant find the answer that's why I posted a question here. teespring.com is achieving the effect I want so it must be possible. Also the Facebook code I'm using is copy and pasted straight from Facebook so I know its the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ (for getting the logged in status) combined with this: [Facebook: get list of pages that a user is admin of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966015/facebook-get-list-of-pages-that-a-user-is-admin-of) (for getting the pages the user is admin of) be solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

put the icons in a container and apply the following css:

```
<style>.social-container{width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden}</style>
```